# Find sum of 2 biggest nonadjacent integers in the array

Tags: java

I found this interview question on some site and thought about it's solution.

The best solution I come to is to iterate over the whole array while saving the 4 biggest numbers and their indices.

After that I will need to find the biggest pair of these numbers ensuring that the selected numbers are not adjacent.

I think this ensures the correct solution to the question but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

My simple code is below.
Can someone give me a better idea to do this?

```
public int findMaxNonAdjacent(int [] array){
    int big1=0, big2=0,big3=0,big4=0;
    int i1=0,i2=0,i3=0,i4=0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]>=big1){
            big4=big3;
            big3=big2;
            big2=big1;
            big1=array[i];
            i4=i3;
            i3=i2;
            i2=i1;
            i1=i;
        }else if(array[i]>=big2){
            big4=big3;
            big3=big2;
            big2=array[i];
            i4=i3;
            i3=i2;
            i2=i;
        }else if(array[i]>=big3){
            big4=big3;
            big3=array[i];
            i4=i3;
            i3=i;
        }else if(array[i]>=big3){
            big4=array[i];
            i4=i;
        }
    }
    if(Math.abs(i1-i2)>1)
        return big1+big2;
    else if(Math.abs(i1-i3)>1){
        return big1+big3;
    }else if((big1+big4>=big2+big3) &&(Math.abs(i1-i4)>1)){
        return big1+big4;
    }else if((big1+big4<=big2+big3) &&(Math.abs(i2-i3)>1)){
        return big2+big3;
    } else
        return big3+big4;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `array` contains only negative numbers? What other corner cases could exist that you might want to check for?

Comment: Well, I can initialize the containers to minimal int values, I thought about this. But currently I do not think there are any corner cases I did not cover.

Comment: so basically you need find two big numbers in an array, and make sure they are not adjacent ?

Comment: @Eliyahu: what if the input array contains only 2 values? or 0?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I assume the array is long enough. But you are right

Comment: @Eliyahu: if you are planning for interview questions then those are the exact kinds of assumptions that you should make explicit. Or even better: suggest to check for them. Even if the interviewer says "yeah, but you don't need to check for them", I'm sure they'll note that you thought about that. The error- or corner-cases are often at least as interesting in an interview as the actual algorithm you end up using.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for a good advice :)
Any more?

Comment: I'm not sure of the question: should you find the biggest sum of two non-adjacent numbers or the two biggest non-adjacent numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Using 1-based indexing; Find the index of the biggest element in the array. If it's `1`, then find the biggest in the range `[3, n]` and return it's sum. If the biggest is at index `n`, then find the biggest in the range `[1, n-2]` and return it's sum. Else if the index of the biggest is `i`, then find the index of the biggest in `[1, i-2]` and the index of the biggest in `[i+2, n]`. Let them be `l` and `r` respectively. Then the answer will be `max(A[i-1] + A[i+1], A[i] + max(A[l], A[r]))`.

Comment: I'm not sure your solution is better than my.

Comment: Actually, his solution is already O(N) time-complexity. To really improve it, you must provide O(logN) time-complexity solution. And the space-complexity is already constant, i.e., O(1).

Comment: @SuryakantBharti to apply some `O(logN)` solution, there needs to be some order to the input. As the input is random, to order it, it'll take `O(NlogN)` time hence the lowerbound for the solution is `O(N)`.

Comment: @Eliyahu your solution requires `4n` comparisons whereas mine requires `2n` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep 4 indices in your code? In my opinion, only 3 elements are sufficient according to pigeonhole principle. Another thing is to check if the input array has less than 3 elements because it's an invalid input.

Comment: I will not argue with principles, but how will you handle the following example: [1,2,3,2,4,3,5,6,5,5,4,2,3] with 3 indices?

Comment: Ooh! I thought that the numbers are unique. Then, continue with your approach.